# How to post many text boxes in one form to databases

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have this script where I want to post values from the form into my database. I want to post many text boxes into one form.

The problem is, only the last text box gets updated.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        echo "<input type='text' name='".$i."' />
        <input type='hidden' name='img_id' value='".$img_id."' />
        <input type='hidden' name='loop' value='".$i."' />";
    }
?>
<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update' /></form>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        //now i need help
        $query = "UPDATE photos SET description = '".$_POST[$_POST['loop']]."' WHERE id = '".$img_id."'";
        $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);
    }
?>
```

For example, loop goes 4 times, that means I have 4 text boxes.

In my script, which is not fully written here, the code updates only the last loop into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use the PHP array notation for the `name` attribute in your HTML. Otherwise you will have multiple inputs with the same `name` and only one of those will be posted

```
echo "<input type='text' name='".$i."' />
      <input type='hidden' name='img_id[]' value='".$img_id."' />
      <input type='hidden' name='loop[]' value='".$i."' />";
```

Now you can access those elements in your PHP as an array.

```
foreach ($_POST['img_id'] as $key=>$value) {
    // img_id's value is in $value
    // loop's value is in $_POST['loop'][$key]
}
```

Use the foreach to build your queries and after the loop execute all of them.

---

Your query is wide open to SQL injections. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) at least (even better: prepared statements, this will also be better performance wise since you always have the same query only different input). Also keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for more information.

Comment: I've used mysql_real_escape_string in my original code :D but I've shortened my codes here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the names of your form elements unique so that they don't clash.  One way would be to post them through as arrays instead:

Also, can't you use the same `$count` variable to loop over the potential results?

It looks like you're posting the hiddens with the name `loop` in order to pass through how many times over the loop you need to go.  If not, you *can* post the loop variable through like this, but you use it in place of `$count` for your update loop.  Also, I'd consider just adding that element in once, at the end - using the value of `$count` instead.

E.g. Something like this may work for you...

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

        // How is img_id set here?  You have no indication in your example - I'll assume that you've put them into an array...

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='img_id[\"".$i.\""]' value='".$img_id[$i]."' />";
        echo "<input type='text' name='name[".$i."]' />";
    }
?>
<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update' /></form>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
            if ( array_key_exists( 'name', $_POST ) && is_array( $_POST['name'] ) && array_key_exists( $i, $_POST['name' ] ) {
                $query = "UPDATE photos SET description = '".$_POST['name'][$i]."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['img_id'][]."'";
                $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Or, if you can't use `$count`:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<?php
    echo( "<input type='hidden' name='loop' value='".$count."' />" );
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

        // How is img_id set here?  You have no indication in your example - I'll assume that you've put them into an array...

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='img_id[\"".$i.\""]' value='".$img_id[$i]."' />";
        echo "<input type='text' name='name[".$i."]' />";
    }
?>
<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update' /></form>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

        for ($i=0; $i<$_POST['loop']; $i++) {

            if ( array_key_exists( 'name', $_POST ) && is_array( $_POST['name'] ) && array_key_exists( $i, $_POST['name'] ) {
                $query = "UPDATE photos SET description = '".$_POST['name'][$i]."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['img_id'][$i]."'";
                $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Kingkero has also made comment on your use of mysql and the fact that you are open to sql injection attacks - do not ignore it!

Comment: `$img_id` is undefined? Also your line with `array_key_exists` could be simplified to `if(isset($_POST['name][$i])) {`

Comment: If `$img_id` is undefined in my script, then it is undefined in the provided example.  As is `$count` - I have assumed that the supplied code is not complete.  Your point about the `if` statement is taken, though I like to be complete on such points for beginners so that it's easier to see what *could* be missing or go wrong.  It may behave the same, but the longer version conveys more information in a tutorial.

Comment: No, actually, it's not.

Comment: @AmirRami No what's not?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I meant that `$img_id` would probably be `$_POST['img_id']` to avoid the "only the last text box gets updated"

Comment: I think it's a fair point - that is likely the underlying problem.  How foolish of me!

Comment: `$img_id` is defined but not written here.

Comment: And, in your loop it never changes, meaning that all the udpates will apply to the same img_id.  That may well be your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use something like,

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

for($i=0; $i<=$_POST['loop']; $i++){
```